# "sam package" command returns "Invalid choice" error

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html

I have a valid S3 bucket with the name: kevinngsw-awssam-quickstart

[image: S3 Bucket]

However, when I attempt to run the following command in my project folder:

```
sam package --s3-bucket kevinngsw-awssam-quickstart --output-template-file packaged.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

cancel-update-stack                      | continue-update-rollback
create-change-set                        | create-stack
delete-change-set                        | delete-stack
describe-account-limits                  | describe-change-set
describe-stack-events                    | describe-stack-resource
describe-stack-resources                 | describe-stacks
estimate-template-cost                   | execute-change-set
get-stack-policy                         | get-template
get-template-summary                     | list-change-sets
list-stack-resources                     | list-stacks
set-stack-policy                         | signal-resource
update-stack                             | validate-template
wait                                     | help
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by updating awscli.